# Using PHP, how can I make a counter that turns any Int into 1 to 9999?

Tags: php, math, modulus

I have an internal counter that counts from 0-999999999999.

I would like this to display as a number between 0-9999, then rollover again.

This means:

- 0 displays as 1
- 1 displays as 2
- 9998 displays as 9999
- ...
- 9999 displays as 1
- 10000 displays as 2
- ...
- 19999 displays as 1
- 20000 displays as 2

edit:

1 + $number % 9999 was the answer (Thanks @Brad Christie). My table of expected results is wrong. (Thanks @Tevo D)

Comment: Have you heard of the modulo (%) operator?

Comment: @djdy, modulo, but I'm having trouble finding an elegant answer that performs consistently across all numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "increasingly large remainders"? % _is_ remainder after division, and is always 0..modulus-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$x = 9280293;
$baseNineNineNineNine = $x % 9999;
```

Use MOD, it will give you the remainder past 9999 (e.g. Any number divided by 9999 can go in N times, with a remainder of Y (you'll end up with Y as a value)

*For the numbers you're looking for, you may want to `+1` any value you get after the MOD (`%`), or use `10000`*

See also the [Modulus Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: @JarebShubway: I'm not sure I get the pattern then. `X % 9999 + 1` gives you what you want, with the `1999` & `20000` edge-cases being the exception. What makes those two numbers special? (See [this example](http://www.ideone.com/xVW1A))

Answer (score 3):

Take reminder with 10000, that guarantees the result to be in between 0 and 9999 and rolls over

```
$result = $int % 10000;
```

Comment: using % 10000 will turn numbers like 20000 into 0, which is not what I want. Adding +1 will turn 9999 into 10000, which is also not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Your table of values doesn't match what you asking for.  In the example you are using 9999 result values (1-9999) for 10000 input values.  In the text you are saying 10000 output values (0-9999).

Here is what I think you are really asking for.  This algorithm will output 1-9999 and then roll over to 1 again.

In other words, this solution will provide a four digit non-zero value:

```
$result = $int % 9999 + 1;
```

The output will NOT match your example, as your example has it rolling over every 10000 values, not 9999.  Here is the output:

```
input   output
0       1
1       2
....      ....
9997      9998
9998      9999
9999      1       <--- 9999 * 1
10000     2
....      ....
19996     9998
19997     9999
19998     1       <--- 9999 * 2
19999     2
....      ....
19995     9998
19996     9999
19997     1       <--- 9999 * 3
19998     2
....      ....
```

Comment: Point taken and good job being the only one to recognize this. Looks like you're right!